# set RAM for proccess before started

Tags: c#, .net, ram

I'm trying to create a GUI for a server,
but when I start the server its complaining that it doesn't have enough ram and when I add the `-Xmx1024M -Xms1024M` to the start command, JAVA is saying it cannot reserve enough space,
but how do I set the reserved RAM for a proccess before it is started?

```
    TekkitServer = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo TekkitStarter = new ProcessStartInfo(@"java", @"-Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar ServerFiles\Tekkit.jar nogui");
    TekkitStarter.UseShellExecute = false;
    TekkitStarter.RedirectStandardError = true;
    TekkitStarter.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    TekkitStarter.CreateNoWindow = true;
    TekkitServer.StartInfo = TekkitStarter;
    TekkitServer.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(TekkitServer_OutputDataReceived);
    TekkitServer.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(TekkitServer_ErrorDataReceived);
    TekkitServer.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    TekkitServer.Start();
    InitializeComponent();
    TekkitServer.BeginErrorReadLine();
    TekkitServer.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

this is the code I got now

**UPDATE:**

when I run `java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar ServerFiles\Tekkit.jar nogui` in CMD it just runs fine and doesn't cry

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I fixed it by upgrading my jre7 32bits to jre7 64bits make sense but now the input doesn't work but problem is solved though

Answer (score 0):

The application automatically allocates the memory required for an operation from the available system memory. It is most likely that you are either using an infinite recursion (which causes the stackoverflow exception because stack is small) or the resources aren't disposed efficiently. You should check your code for these problems.

Comment: there is no loop in anyway so there is no recursion but its just works fine when I run the bat file

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses Then try creating a bat file and execute it ?

Comment: I just did but that only works when I run it in CMD itself not from the bat file

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses You need to set `UseShellExecute` to `true`.

Comment: doesnt work then I cant redirect the input and output what is a must